# How do I produce a node module using dotnet-fable

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I have a project that I've created with `dotnet fable new -n ProjectName` and if I run it with webpack server everything works as expected. However I want to create an Express server. For that I thought I would simply create a node module and then run that. But when I look at the help text from `dotnet fable --help` I can't find a way to tell fable to just compile the js and to let me chose where those files should be placed. So question how do I tell dotnet-fable to produce js files (and do nothing else).

p.s. using the fable-cli results in a null reference (likely due to the project file structure) which is why I haven't just used that

Answer (score 1):

I just wrestled with the same thing.  When using the fable template, `dotnet fable npm-run build` just builds JS files for me.  Try removing the `devServer` section from webpack.config.js, and changing your "start" script in package.json to say `webpack && node bundle.js`.  (The `devServer` feature in webpack starts up its own simple express.js backend - something I just learned while building my own fable express app)